# preloader by jquery before loading a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two page one is `index.html` and another is `page.html` and also have a `loading.gif` I want to setup my `index.html` for loading with gif. If don't have Internet connection `index.html` loading until Internet connection with `loading.gif`. If have Internet connection after 5 second loading it will automatically redirect to `page.html`.

I completely want to do it using jquery.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show loader on page index.html once loaded.

And then by below logic you can check connectivity and write redirection logic.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.html",
    timeout: 10000, //your time
    error: function(jqXHR) { 
        if(jqXHR.status==0) {
            alert(" fail to connect, please check your connection settings");
        }
    },
    success: function() {
        alert(" your connection is alright!");
        //redirect to page.html
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but I want to do this in same page. all of html content in index.html with preloader if have Internet connection preloader will hide within 5 second. else it won't hide. only preloader will be showing until Internet connection. please how can I do it.

Comment: What do u mean same page here? Can you please explain detail your requirement.

Comment: that means I dont want to redirect page.html I just want to hide loader if have Internet connection. if doesnt have it will be loading until Internet connection all html content will be in index.html with loader.

Comment: In this case then do not write any redirection logic other then removing loaded logic in the success. Set timeout value as per your requirement

Comment: Assuming <imd src"loader.gif"  id="loaderImg"/> is the image you are using to show loader on index.html,  In success you can remove this from the page using code $("#loaderImg").hide();